# Error:This application requires .NET framework 4.0 Client Profile RTM

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8

I'm running Visual studio 2010 with SP1 on Windows 8 Developer Preview. When I try to install Entity framework 4.1 I get the following error:

[image]

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: The MSI probably doesn't account for Windows 8 yet. You might be able to remove the install precondition with a tool like Orca. Even if you do, no guarantees that it would actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just installed ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1 - Update 1 from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26825 and everything started working correctly.